# Can't find apache config redirect in config files

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

**the goal**
Redirecting mydomain.com/something to mysite.com/something

**the problem**
Any domain that you throw at the server gets 302 redirected to www.mysite.com and, for the life of me, I can't find the config rule that is doing this!

**what i've done so far**
I've grepped everything in the /etc/apache2 folder for 'mysite.com', 'Redirect', 'redirect', and other, as well as scour by hand all the apache config files looking for this redirect rule to no avail.

Any and all help in finding the culprit redirect is greatly appreciated. I'm not a sysadmin so there must be a place I don't know of where this might be other than the /etc/apache2 folder...

Thank you kindly for helping me with my first SO question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with an .htaccess in the docroot of another domain on the server. This other domain was higher alphabetically and was treated as the default domain.
I solved the problem by creating a new vhost for the domain that i wanted to redirect and it was handled properly.
Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The file which includes redirection rules does not have to be in /etc/apache2 folder.  Check your document root folder (the path of which you can find in your vhost configuration file) for .htaccess files. They may have redirect rules too.

Comment: i checked the .htaccess file but all this is happening way before the request hits the docroot    
thank you for your help

Comment: Please also check if there are any mod_rewrite rules anywhere in your configurations.

Comment: I scanned the config files by hand and grepped for rewrite and Rewrite looking for this but no avail.  The config i'm looking for is actually doing 302 redirects on EVERY domain that hits the server, but i can't find it...